# Importing Excel file with formula values

Tags: excel, csv

This is probably an elementary question but I couldn't find an answer in a search specific enough...

I am receiving a CSV file from our credit card processing company and want to open it up in Excel and then apply a formula to some of the data, and then import the Excel file, with the resulting value, into Quickbooks. Can a field with a formula value be imported?(not really a Qucikbook question but more of a general question about importing CSV files) If so, how can I get the receiving program (Qucikbooks) to ignore the formula? Is it as simple as not using a column header in the column that contains the formula?

Thanks in advance!

JC

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Excel 2010:

If you truly have a CSV file, then add some formula fields.  When you try to save the file, Excel will warn you that saving it as a CSV may drop some of your features you have in the sheet. You will want to save it as a CSV anyway.

Once saved, the formulas will be removed and only the value in the cells will be saved.